# How do I create a text channel then send a message in that new channel?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a new text channel, then have the bot send a message inside that channel.

The code I am using:

```
let everyoneRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === '@everyone');

const MafiaChannel = message.guild.channels.create('mafia', {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                id: everyoneRole.id,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                },{
                id: PlayersShuffled[0].id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                }
            ]
        })

        client.channels.cache.get(MafiaChannel.id).send("Who do you want to kill?")
```

The response I am getting:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Comment: channels.create is a Promise, await it and then you can use MafiChannel.send()

Answer (score 0):

The methode [`GuildChannelManger#create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) returns the channel as a promise. So you should await is, to make sure that he channel has been created, and then send the message.

```
const MafiaChannel = await message.guild.channels.create('mafia');
MafiaChannel.send("Who do you want to kill?");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/CategoryCreateChannelOptions), you should be using [ChannelType](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ChannelType) enum for creating channels and name shouldn't be the first parameter.

Moreover, sending messages as strings are deprecated, you should use

```js
Channel#send({content: "your content"})
```

instead.

Also when you getting "everyone" role, you should be using `message.guild.roles.everyone`

so to make it creates the channel and send a message

```js
var channel = await message.guild.channels.create({
    name: "mafia",
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
        deny: [
          PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel,
          PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages,
        ],
      },
      {
        id: PlayersShuffled[0].id,
        allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
      }
    ],
  });
channel.send({content: "Close your eyes"});
```